# Передать Context в Model MVP

Tags: android, mvp

обьясните пожалуйста. 
Собственно для работы с базой данных нужен контекст.
Не совсем понимаю как правильно передать его в модель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый просто это передать в модель Application Context.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

В манифесте

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">

</application>
```

Так вы можете получить контекст Application из любой точки приложения.  Для большинства случаев это верное решение.

Если же из каких-то соображений вам это не подходит, то обычно в Presenter вы имеете ссылку на View которая либо сама является контекстом (Activity) либо же имеет ссылку на контекст (Fragment, View).

Comment: а никаких утечек не будет, если сохранять ссылку на контекст в статической переменной?

Comment: В данном случае нет. У вас Application живет пока живет приложение и он может быть единственным. Во всех остальных случаях ваше замечание верно.